Can I run variations of my XUnit test class?
When adding a feature flag to some code, I want a way of executing the existing code both with and without the flag applied to ensure that switching it on/off does not break existing code.
Let's say I have the following class and tests:
public class TestSubject
{
    public void EnsureNumberIsOdd(int inputValue)
    {
        if (inputValue % 2 != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be an odd number", paramName: nameof(inputValue));
    }
}

public class UnitTest2
{
    private readonly TestSubject Subject;

    public UnitTest2()
    {
        Subject = new TestSubject();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2)]
    [InlineData(4)]
    [InlineData(6)]
    public void WhenValueIsEven_ThenThrowsException(int inputValue)
    {
        var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => Subject.EnsureNumberIsOdd(inputValue));
        Assert.Equal("inputValue", exception!.ParamName);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    [InlineData(3)]
    [InlineData(5)]
    public void WhenValueIsOdd_ThenDoesNotThrowException(int inputValue)
    {
        Subject.EnsureNumberIsOdd(inputValue);
    }
}

Now somebody decides there is a new requirement that the inputValue must be less than 11, but they also want this hidden behind a feature toggle.
using Moq;
public interface IFeatureFlags
{
    bool IsFlagEnabled(string flagName);
}

public class TestSubject(IFeatureFlags FeatureFlags)
{
    public void EnsureNumberIsOdd(int inputValue)
    {
        if (inputValue % 2 != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must be an odd number", paramName: nameof(inputValue));

        if (FeatureFlags.IsFlagEnabled("ValueMustBeLessThan11"))
            ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfGreaterThanOrEqual(inputValue, 11);
    }
}

public class UnitTest2
{
    private readonly Mock<IFeatureFlags> MockFeatureFlags;
    private readonly TestSubject Subject;
    private bool FeatureFlagIsEnabled;

    public UnitTest2()
    {
        MockFeatureFlags = new Mock<IFeatureFlags>();
        MockFeatureFlags
            .Setup(x => x.IsFlagEnabled("ValueMustBeLessThan11"))
            .Returns(() => FeatureFlagIsEnabled);

        Subject = new TestSubject(MockFeatureFlags.Object);
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(2)]
    [InlineData(4)]
    [InlineData(6)]
    public void WhenValueIsEven_ThenThrowsException(int inputValue)
    {
        // Same as before
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    [InlineData(3)]
    [InlineData(5)]
    public void WhenValueIsOdd_ThenDoesNotThrowException(int inputValue)
    {
        // Same as before
    }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenFeatureFlagIsOn_AndValueIsNotLessThan10_ThenThrowsException()
    {
        FeatureFlagIsEnabled = true;
        foreach(int i in new[] { 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 })
        {
            var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => Subject.EnsureNumberIsOdd(i));
            Assert.Equal("inputValue", exception!.ParamName);
        }
    }
}



I have added an IFeatureFlags interface, and injected it into the TestSubject.
I have added a new test to ensure an exception is thrown if the value is not less than 11.

What I really need to do is ensure that the original two tests both pass when the feature flag is true or false. My options are

Loop through values [true, false].


Problem: The two checks don't run in isolation. For subjects with state this can cause failures.


Duplicate the [InlineData] attributes and have true for the first half and false for the second half.


Problem: Someone might not add both true and false [InlineData] when adding a new  scenario.
Problem: Adding new feature flags to the same code causes combinations grow exponentially, which is too much to manage and likely to be wrong.


Duplicate the tests.


Problem: As above, but duplicating test methods is far more complicated than duplicating [InlineData] attributes.

I had considered using a [ClassData] attribute for all variations of all flags, but I am unable to combine their inputs with the existing [InlineData] attributes, so I had to give up on that idea.
I currently loop through all variations in each test and ensuring I re-initialise all state on each loop, but this makes me sick a little bit in my mouth whenever I look at it.
Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Have you looked at Xunit.Combinatorial? https://daninacan.com/how-to-run-every-possible-combination-of-arguments-in-xunit

What if you simplified your tests to [InlineData(1, true)] and [InlineData(1, false)] for the odd test and [InlineData(2, true)] and [InlineData(2, false)] for the even test. With the remaining [Fact] this covers all possible branches of logic.

As per the question. This grows exponentially. 1 flag = 2 variations, 2 flags = 4, 3 flags = 8 - and then the developer is unlikely to get them all correct. I'm looking for a better way.

Hi @JonSkeet - Yes!! I've tried it and it does exactly what I need. It even lets me have all variations of flags + inline data. Thank you!

Hooray. I suggest you write your own answer in that case, rather than me doing so, as it'll be better tailored to your specific use case.

As suggested by Jon Skeet, I used the Xunit.Combinatorial library and it works very nicely!
